# mysql connection in OOP way and closing the connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a php class to connect to MySQL DB. It works fine. My question is, I am not sure whether my code is closing the connection at the end. how to make sure that the connection has been closed? any kind of suggestions?

DbConnect.php

```
Class DbClass{
    function getdbconnect(){
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'myDB') or die("Couldn't connect");
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

main.php

```
require_once('DbConnect.php');  #including the file
$Dbobj = new DbClass();         #object of the DbClass
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myDB";

if($result = mysqli_query($Dbobj->getdbconnect(), $sql))
  {
      #some actions
  }

mysqli_free_result($result);  #is this right?
mysqli_close($Dbobj->getdbconnect());  #is this the right way to close the #connection
```

Comment: If you are not using persistent connections, PHP closes them automatically at script end anyway …

Comment: okay. perfect ;)

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect